# Rendering issue with a record from Database in Chrome using JSF

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm using a standard f:viewParam in my XHTML page to load a certain record from DB before rendering the page. This works just perfect when I DON'T use Chrome as browser. So, in Firefox, Safari and Edge the page gets rendered as expected containing detailed information about the requested record.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
  xmlns:kf="http://wspsoft.de/kolibri/platform/faces" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="addressId" value="#{newAddressCRBean.addressId}"/>
  <f:viewParam name="formView" value="#{newAddressCRBean.formView}"/>
</f:metadata>
...
```

But when using Chrome in about 80% of all times the page gets rendered, but no data is shown, only empty p:inputFields and p:outputLabels. The other 20% the page gets rendered correctly.

In the log I can see that the right function gets called from the f:viewParam just like in the successfull cases, containing the right ID for the record. After hitting the refresh button the page ALWAYS gets rendered correctly, containing useful information about the requested record.

Does anybody have any idea what's different in Chrome compared to the other brothers and how I can force Chrome to behave correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try disabling all browser extensions/plugins first.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, but didn't help. I'm a Firefox guy, though I didn't had any extras on my Chrome anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it fixed, even though I'm still not 100% sure what went wrong. Root cause of my problem was the ViewScope of my beans and this mechanism (http://javaevangelist.blogspot.de/2014/08/jsf-21-tip-of-day-clearing-viewscope.html) to fix an issue with ViewScoped Beans and garbage collection. Somehow the bean was killed and reinstantiated at some random point of time when the page got rendered, causing the strange effects mentioned in my original post.

I solved the problem by rewriting John Rearys tip, to not remove the latest view, but keep a list of 10 views and always removing the oldest one from the list.

Why exactly Chrome provoqued that strange behaviour and all the other browsers d
didn't I can't tell, but I guess it has something to do with Chromes inner speed optimizations.

Comment: So you're using an ancient JSF 2.x version for which this "fix" was necessary? I'm asking this because this should be unnecessary in JSF 2.2 but you tagged [jsf-2.2]. Nonetheless, are you aware of existence of OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`? http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped

Comment: No, we're using Mojarra v2.2.13. Didn't know that this fix is unnecessary. We had some memory issues about a year ago and the fix helped to solve it. I guess I should spend an hour or two to check, whether the fix is still required.

Yes, I'm aware of OmniFaces and I would really like to use it, but we're using a rather complicated approach of inner-dependent fully generated web-applications, where OmniFaces caused some really bad problems. We're currently refactoring the architecture from multiple war files to one EAR. Maybe we can give OmniFace another try then.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue using @SessionScoped in the jsf 2.0. This is probably some bug